# Spring pagination - request parameters

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

My REST contorller:

```
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public Page<MyObject> pathParamTest(Pageable pageable) {
        return myService.getPage(pageable);
    }
```

I send a request like following:

```
localhost:8091/endpoint/test?page=0&size=3&sort=id&direction=DESC
```

It's my response from server:

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 3
        }
    ],
    "last": true,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "totalElements": 3,
    "first": true,
    "sort": [
        {
            "direction": "ASC",
            "property": "id",
            "ignoreCase": false,
            "nullHandling": "NATIVE",
            "descending": false,
            "ascending": true
        }
    ],
    "numberOfElements": 3,
    "size": 3,
    "number": 0
}
```

but the request has still direction = ASC.

How can I send to server direction = DESC?

And why response has a field "last" = true, because next page has one element more?

Comment: No, I didn't find nothing about my problem. When I write phrases: "spring pagination", "spring pageable" I get articles from '14 using ModelView.

Comment: Oh, okey. I forgot that everyone is an expert. Forgive that you had to write this post... Pathetic...

Comment: I have an additional question closely related to this one if anyone knows the answer, but I don't think this is possible. How do we pass the ignoreCase param on the query? 

I hoped it would be as simple as:-

curl -v "http://localhost:8080/people/search/nameStartsWith?name=K&sort=name,desc,true" but it's not :-(

Answer (score 47, accepted):

try 
localhost:8091/endpoint/test?page=0&size=3&sort=id,DESC

from [spring data rest 6.2. Sorting](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#paging-and-sorting.sorting)

> curl -v
>   "http://localhost:8080/people/search/nameStartsWith?name=K&sort=name,desc"
>
> sort  Properties that should be sorted by in the format
>   property,property(,ASC|DESC). Default sort direction is ascending. Use
>   multiple sort parameters if you want to switch directions, e.g.
>   ?sort=firstname&sort=lastname,asc.