# How to format a Pageable json object in javascript sending direction of query to Spring API

Tags: javascript, angular, spring, jpa, pageable

I want to send as a part of a Pageable object the direction/order of a query "**ASC**" or "**DESC**". So my problem is that even if I set the direction as value of pageable and the API URL Request has this information in it, the Spring backend does not correctly parse the Pageble object and it always shows **ASC** as direction (I think this may be the default state).

This is my filter method in Angular controller

```
Controller.prototype.sortByDate = function(asc_desc, isStartDate){
        this.pageable.sort = isStartDate ? "validityStartDate" : "validityEndDate";
        this.pageable.direction = asc_desc;
        this.service.findAll(this.filter, this.pageable).then(function(data){
            this.magazineCollectionSubscriptionList = data.content;
            this.setupPagination( data.totalElements );
            this.changePageSize(size, this.filter);
        }.bind(this));
    }
```

This is my API call in the Service of this entity

```
Service.prototype.findAll = function(filter, pageable){
        return this.httpService.post(this.serviceUrl + '/list',filter, { params: pageable });
};
```

This is the request it creates

[image]

And here is what the debug show on IDE

[image]

Comment: can you show your api whether its expecting pageable as pathvariable or requestparam. or requestbody?

Comment: public Page<BasicCompanyMagazineCollectionSubscription> findAll(@RequestBody BasicCompanyMagazineCollectionSubscriptionFilter filter, Pageable pageable){

Comment: but you are not taking pageable neither in queryparams, nor in requestbody nor in path variable for api. so how will api receive it? shouldn't you also mark it with @RequestParam?

Comment: I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44757218/spring-pagination-request-parameters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring pagination - request parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44757218/spring-pagination-request-parameters)